# for loop when matching both front and back of file name

Tags: bash, command-line, filenames, bioinformatics

I'm trying to set up a for loop to run a process on pairs of files.  The names of the files look like this

```
36_002_CGATGT_L001_R1_005.fastq.gz
36_002_CGATGT_L001_R2_005.fastq.gz

36_002_CGATGT_L001_R1_002.fastq.gz
36_002_CGATGT_L001_R2_002.fastq.gz

62_013_AGTCAA_L001_R1_003.fastq.gz
62_013_AGTCAA_L001_R2_003.fastq.gz
```

I need to use each pair in the following command

```
sickle pe -f 36_002_CGATGT_L001_R1_005.fastq.gz \
 -r 36_002_CGATGT_L001_R2_005.fastq.gz\
 -o trimmed_36_002_CGATGT_L001_R1_005.fastq.gz\
 -p trimmed_36_002_CGATGT_L001_R2_005.fastq.gz\
 -s 36_002_CGATGT_L001_singles_005.fastq.gz
```

To begin with I'm trying:

```
for n in *R1*; do m='basename $n R2' ; echo $m; done
```

but clearly this approach isn't working because the both the front and back of the file name are important.  Do I need to rename files so the R1 and R2 are the last part of the name?  Which would be awkward but not impossible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your shell supports the ksh `${var/search/replace}` form of parameter expansion (`ksh93`, `zsh`, `mksh`, `yash`, `bash`):

```
for r1 in *R1*; do
  r2=${r1/R1/R2}
  singles=${r1/R1/singles}
  trimmed1=trimmed$r1
  trimmed2=trimmed$r2
  sickle pe -f "$r1" \
   -r "$r2" \
   -o "$trimmed1" \
   -p "$trimmed2" \
   -s "$singles"
done
```

POSIXly, you could do

```
 r2=${r1%%R1*}R2${r1#*R1}
```

Comment: your answer did what I asked for, but I realized an error in my question.  have fixed it in the question and in your answer, in case any other sickle users happen on this solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you're looking for, you could solve it using `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *_R1_*; do 
    file=`basename $file`
    newFile=`echo $file | awk -F '_R1_' '{print $1}'`_R2_`echo $file | awk -F '_R1_' '{print $2}'`
    sName=`echo $file | awk -F '_R1_' '{print $1}'`_singles_`echo $file | awk -F '_R1_' '{print $2}'`
    echo $newFile
    rName="$newFile"
    oName="trimmed_$file"
    pName="$file"
done
```