# Take similarly named fastq files on a folder and amke them input for an script(on pairs)

Tags: files, scripting, directory, parallelism, bioinformatics

I have a set of files named like this inside a folder:

```
AM11_BW415_R1.fastq.gz         NAM13_BW968_R2.fastq.gz     NAM17_AC_Barrie_R1.fastq.gz  NAM3_PI648600_R2.fastq.gz  NAM7_Glenlea_R1.fastq.gz   PI648598_R2.fastq.gz
NAM11_BW415_R2.fastq.gz         NAM13_Frontana_R1.fastq.gz  NAM17_AC_Barrie_R2.fastq.gz  NAM3_PI648842_R1.fastq.gz  NAM7_Glenlea_R2.fastq.gz   PI648611_R1.fastq.gz
NAM11_Reeder_R1.fastq.gz        NAM13_Frontana_R2.fastq.gz  NAM17_BW388_R1.fastq.gz      NAM3_PI648842_R2.fastq.gz  NAM7_Laura_R1.fastq.gz     PI648611_R2.fastq.gz
NAM11_Reeder_R2.fastq.gz        NAM14_BW874_R1.fastq.gz     NAM17_BW388_R2.fastq.gz      NAM4_PI613279_R1.fastq.gz  NAM7_Laura_R2.fastq.gz     PI648672_R1.fastq.gz
NAM11_Webill_R1.fastq.gz        NAM14_BW874_R2.fastq.gz     NAM17_RedFife_R1.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI613279_R2.fastq.gz  NAM7_Marquis_R1.fastq.gz   PI648672_R2.fastq.gz
NAM11_Webill_R2.fastq.gz        NAM14_Glenn_R1.fastq.gz     NAM17_RedFife_R2.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI613280_R1.fastq.gz  NAM7_Marquis_R2.fastq.gz   PI648724_R1.fastq.gz
NAM12_BW431_L002_R1.fastq.gz    NAM14_Glenn_R2.fastq.gz     NAM1_PI648517_R1.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI613280_R2.fastq.gz  NAM8_FL62R1_R1.fastq.gz    PI648724_R2.fastq.gz
NAM12_BW431_L002_R2.fastq.gz    NAM14_Unity_R1.fastq.gz     NAM1_PI648517_R2.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI648524_R1.fastq.gz  NAM8_FL62R1_R2.fastq.gz    PI648768_R1.fastq.gz
NAM12_BW431_L008_R1.fastq.gz    NAM14_Unity_R2.fastq.gz     NAM1_PI648519_R1.fastq.gz    NAM4_PI648524_R2.fastq.gz  NAM8_Muchmore_R1.fastq.gz  PI648768_R2.fastq.gz
NAM12_BW431_L008_R2.fastq.gz    NAM15_BW881_R1.fastq.gz     NAM1_PI648519_R2.fastq.gz    NAM5_PI648523_R1.fastq.gz  NAM8_Muchmore_R2.fastq.gz  PI648860_R1.fastq.gz
NAM12_Penhold_L002_R1.fastq.gz  NAM15_BW881_R2.fastq.gz     NAM1_PI648541_R1.fastq.gz    NAM5_PI648523_R2.fastq.gz  NAM8_Stettler_R1.fastq.gz  PI648860_R2.fastq.gz
NAM12_Penhold_L002_R2.fastq.gz  NAM15_Lillian_R1.fastq.gz   NAM1_PI648541_R2.fastq.gz    NAM5_PI648585_R1.fastq.gz  NAM8_Stettler_R2.fastq.gz  PI648862_R1.fastq.gz
NAM12_Penhold_L008_R1.fastq.gz  NAM15_Lillian_R2.fastq.gz   NAM2_PI648493_R1.fastq.gz    NAM5_PI648585_R2.fastq.gz  PI277012_R1.fastq.gz       PI648862_R2.fastq.gz
NAM12_Penhold_L008_R2.fastq.gz  NAM15_PT245_R1.fastq.gz     NAM2_PI648493_R2.fastq.gz    NAM5_PI648622_R1.fastq.gz  PI277012_R2.fastq.gz       PI648864_R1.fastq.gz
NAM12_Sumai3_L002_R1.fastq.gz   NAM15_PT245_R2.fastq.gz     NAM2_PI648602_R1.fastq.gz    NAM5_PI648622_R2.fastq.gz  PI648478_R1.fastq.gz       PI648864_R2.fastq.gz
NAM12_Sumai3_L002_R2.fastq.gz   NAM16_BA51B92_R1.fastq.gz   NAM2_PI648602_R2.fastq.gz    NAM6_Neepawa_R1.fastq.gz   PI648478_R2.fastq.gz       run_701_150904_7001410_0194_BC79VNANXX_NAM.list
NAM12_Sumai3_L008_R1.fastq.gz   NAM16_BA51B92_R2.fastq.gz   NAM2_PI648609_R1.fastq.gz    NAM6_Neepawa_R2.fastq.gz   PI648487_R1.fastq.gz       run_760_160912_7001343F_0065_AC9EV0ANXX_NAM.list
NAM12_Sumai3_L008_R2.fastq.gz   NAM16_BW928_R1.fastq.gz     NAM2_PI648609_R2.fastq.gz    NAM6_PI648532_R1.fastq.gz  PI648487_R2.fastq.gz
NAM13_BW462_R1.fastq.gz         NAM16_BW928_R2.fastq.gz     NAM3_PI648511_R1.fastq.gz    NAM6_PI648532_R2.fastq.gz  PI648566_R1.fastq.gz
NAM13_BW462_R2.fastq.gz         NAM16_BW963_R1.fastq.gz     NAM3_PI648511_R2.fastq.gz    NAM6_Thatcher_R1.fastq.gz  PI648566_R2.fastq.gz
NAM13_BW968_R1.fastq.gz         NAM16_BW963_R2.fastq.gz     NAM3_PI648600_R1.fastq.gz    NAM6_Thatcher_R2.fastq.gz  PI648598_R1.fastq.gz
```

so I want to do for loops or a single for loop that is able to take two similarly named files for example 
NAM11_Reeder_R1.fastq.gz
and
and then submit them as arguments for a script outside of that folder in the following way:

```
 scripts/PipelineHaplo.sh raw/NAM13_BW968_R1.fastq.gz raw/NAM13_BW968_R2.fastq.gz 2 &
```

The 2 designates the depth of the reads but for simplicity sake lets say it is a constant and different argument that I can pretty much hardcode.

Then I want it to grab the next two arguments (raw files) R1 and R2 and do the same.
How can I then do that withouth having the script applying the argumetns on the incorrect folders.
Basically all this is inside a main folder and the folders inside it are:
The Raw files 
The scripts
A big set of basically empty directories called cases{001...008} with subdirecttories on them

and that's where I want the script to work so the script first is basically first of all going to move R1 and R2 to a folder called raw and on raw is where the next script takes control of that and does its job.

How this loop that takes the files two by two only the similarly named, would look like?

Comment: Presumably related: [for loop when matching both front and back of file name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186623/for-loop-when-matching-both-front-and-back-of-file-name)

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
parallel scripts/PipelineHaplo.sh {} '{=s/_R1/_R2/=}' 2 ::: raw/*R1.fastq.gz
```